# global namespace issue with jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with calling a jquery defined function from the global name space after my initial page load.  Based on my code below the page loads fine initially but when I try calling my onchange event I'm getting the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My jquery code looks like this:

```
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {

      var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
      var identifier = $('#identifier').val();

      $.getPostFeed(user_id, identifier);

      $(document).on("change", "#postFilter", function(e) { 
          e.preventDefault ();
          $.GetPostFeed(user_id, identifier);
      });

  });

  jQuery.getPostFeed = function getPostFeed(user_id, identifier) {

      console.log("Function Called");
  }

}(jQuery));
```

***When I first load the page, the GetPostFeed function is executed successfully but when I perform on onchange event I get the following error:***

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error points back to the GetPostFeed function call in the change event.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: All other instances of `GetPostFeed` have a lowercase `g`.

Comment: crap...can't believe I missed that. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue as pointed out by Matt.  jquery is case-sensitive. Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function as an expression, the arguments follow the `function` keyword immediately. Try changing

`jQuery.getPostFeed = function getPostFeed(user_id, identifier) {`

to

`jQuery.getPostFeed = function(user_id, identifier) {`

Comment: the syntax `jQuery.getPostFeed = function getPostFeed(user_id, identifier) {}` is perfectly valid in JavaScript code, try it in your browser's console ! ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's **valid**, and I didn't know that!. Useless IMO, though, since in `var x = function y(args) { ... }` the identifier `y` is kind of declared but rever reachable. Makes for less readable/mainteable code.

Comment: It's more useful than you might think :) the identifier `y` is reachable inside the function itself (and only there), so it might be used for some kind of recursion for example. It's also useful to have `function y` in the stack trace instead of a bunch of `(anonymous function)`. You can learn more about it here http://kangax.github.io/nfe/ and here https://medium.com/@cramforce/on-the-awesomeness-of-fn-displayname-9511933a714a.

Answer (score 0):

i got your problem:

```
  <script>
   //use
   $.getPostFeed(user_id, identifier);
   //instead of
   // $.GetPostFeed(user_id, identifier);
  </script>
```

Its only a alphabetical case problem : USE "getPostFeed" instead of "GetPostFeed".

Either your is fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a namespace globally, then you have to use always the same.

Ex. If you use `$` so, in all places you should use the same function `$` and not using the keyword `jQuery`.

Try the code below:

```
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {
  var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
  var identifier = $('#identifier').val();

  $.getPostFeed(user_id, identifier);

      $(document).on("change", "#postFilter", function(e) { 
          e.preventDefault ();
          $.GetPostFeed(user_id, identifier);
      });

  });

  $.getPostFeed = function getPostFeed(user_id, identifier) {

      console.log("Function Called");
  }

}($));
```